# Removing number from a single page, but keeping the header?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

How can I remove the number from a single page, but still have the header unchanged?
I want to remove the number, and all the ways i have tried, the header is removed as well, or the header is replaced with the page number.

I'm using `fancyhdr` to define my header and footer in general.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{name}
\chead{}
\rhead{affiliation}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} %removes both header and footer (dont want that)
\newpage

\pagestyle{headings} %footer is gone, but header shows the page number,
and not what i have set the header to be

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: `! Undefined control sequence.
l.23 \lipsum`

Answer (score 2):

You can define a new page style with an empty foot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{name}
\chead{}
\rhead{affiliation}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{zzz}{
\lhead{name}
\chead{}
\rhead{affiliation}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{}
}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{zzz} % empty foot
\lipsum
\newpage


and not what i have set the header to be

\end{document}
```